# How can I create a code that translates a string sentence to Pyglatin?

Tags: python, translate

I have a python code to translate a one worded string to pyglatin and is as follows:

```
pyg = 'ay'
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
if len(original)>0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    rest = word[1:]
    new_word = rest+first+pyg
print new_word
```

However, I'm stumped on how to translate an entire sentence to Pyglatin. The problem I'm working on has these following conditions: for words that begin with consonants, all initial consonants are moved to the end of the word and 'ay' is appended. For words that begin with a vowel, the initial vowel remains, but 'way' is added to the end of the word.
As an example, the string 'How are you today?' would be 'owhay areway uoyay odaytay?'

Answer (score 0):

Read in a sentence.  Break it into individual words (**split** method).  Translate each word to Pig Latin.  Concatenate the translations.

Does that get you moving?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Use split and put it into an empty string.

```
original = raw_input("Enter Sentence: ")
conversion = ""
for word in original.split():
    if len(word)>0 and word.isalpha():
        word = word.lower()
        first = word[0]
        rest = word[1:]
        pyg = "ay"
        pygword = rest+first+pyg
        conversion += pygword + " "
print conversion
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try, but if you are not doing it yourself at least try to understand it. (You are free to ask of course)
This has basic ability to deal with special characters like the "?"

```
def pygword(word):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    if     word[0] in vowels:
        return word + 'way'
    else:
        while word[0] not in vowels:
            word = word[1:]+word[0]
        return word + "ay"

def pygsentence(sentence):
    final = ''
    for word in sentence.lower().split():   #split the sentence
        #words should only end in symols in correct grammar
        if word[-1] in '.,;:!?':
            symbol = word[-1]
            word = word[:-1]
        else:
            symbol = ''

        if word.isalpha(): #check if word is alphanumerically
            final += pygword(word)+symbol+' '
        else:
            return "There is a strange thing in one of your words."

    return final[:-1]    #remove last unecessary space
```

There may be faster, more robust, simpler, better understandable ways to do this, but this how I would start.

Test yields me:

```
In[1]: pygsentence("How are you today? I am fine, thank you very much good sir!")
Out[1]: 'owhay areway ouyay odaytay? iway amway inefay, ankthay ouyay eryvay uchmay oodgay irsay!'
```

Your code does not obey the vowel/consonant rule, so I did my own converter for single words.

Just realized that it won't be able to deal with apastrophes in the middle of words (we don't really have theese in german ;) ) so there is a little task left for you.

edit: I did not know in which order you wanted the consonants apended, since that became not clear from your example. So i made an alternative `pygword` function:

```
def pygword2(word):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    if word[0] in vowels:
        return word + 'way'
    else:
        startcons = ''
        while word[0] not in vowels:
            startcons =  word[0] +startcons
            word = word[1:]
        word = word+startcons
        return word + "ay"
```

See the differnece:

`In[48]: pygword("street")
Out[48]: 'eetstray'
In[49]: pygword2("street")
Out[49]: 'eetrtsay'`

Comment: You're code worked great and the first version was what I was looking for so thanks for that. Originally I had this code going after someone mentioned the split method but I couldn't get the rest of it and I don't want to copy your code exactly.
def pyglatin(e):
    vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u')
    newstr = ""
    x = e.lower().split()
    for u in x:
        if i[0] in vowels:
            return i + 'way' + ' '
        else:
            while i[0] not in vowels:
                i = i[1:] + i[0] + 'ay' + ' '

this is as far as I got where it made sense to me.

Comment: FWIW, there's no need to make those unwieldy lists. Eg, `vowels = 'aeiou'` also works for doing `in` tests of single characters.

Comment: tahnks @PM2Ring that makes total sense, I changed the code accordingly